# Search and Find using input form and SQL DB and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sql, excel, search

I am looking to create a mobile friendly input where a user can input 2 different zip codes (origin zip & dest zip), they are returned information from a Database about those zips.

Companies like Fedex and UPS use zip code ranges to determine shipping information.

So it would need to search about 60,000 line items to find the exact range that fits both zip codes, and then returns the 5 values that are on the right.

The link below is a screen shot of what excel looks like and the data wanted to return
[Screenshot](http://www.carpenoctem.tv/Capture.JPG)

So if the origin zip was (for example) 33705 and the destination was 31601, it would search the origin range and the destination range, and return

3
303
203
133
103

After that works, then will move on to do bigger and better things... but this is the first step.

What is the best way to code something like this?

Comment: To sit down and write it...

I would recommend using something like jQuery `ajax` to do your database queries. In addition, if you wanted to stick with the Excel file only, there are plenty of ways to interact with the Excel sheet too.

Comment: I am looking to try and get something that would be able to be accessed when i am not attached the computer....  is Ajax and jquery programs? or languages?  Sorry... i am new when it comes to this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Web services are what you're looking for. Create web services that will interact with your database. Whenever your user enter origin and destination zip then call the service and send these entered zip codes as parameters of web service. Services will do rest of the computation i.e. finding 5 zip codes in between the given zip codes and returning the result back to the user.

Comment: is there a specific one that you would recommend??  what language woudl it be programmed in??

Comment: web services can be in any platform, you can create in .net (asmx/wcf services) or php web services. It totally depends on where your comfort zone lies.